# Can't store output of jq in variable

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have some text that I want to escape to something I can use in JSON.
I can escape the text using jq and display it

```
normaltext="My normal text that I want to put in \"JSON\""
echo $normaltext | jq --slurp --raw-input
```

> "My normal text that I want to put in \"JSON\"\n"

However, store that command output into a variable, jq doesn't seem to receive the input and just displays the help text.

```
escapedtext=$(echo $normaltext | jq --slurp --raw-input)
```

> jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe]
>   Usage: jq [options]  [file...]

Comment: can't reproduce, works fine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your version of jq evidently requires the `.` filter here, as in:

```
 jq -s -R .
```

Comment: That works.  Thanks!  But I don't understand why it didn't work without the dot when I tried to capture the output of the subshell.  It even worked when I put parenthesis around without the dollar.

Comment: Those not clearly documented, it appears you can only omit the `.` when `jq` can detect its standard output is a terminal.